# Why I have wrong output java headfirst?

Tags: java

I am a beginner in java. I'm doing exercise page 90 chapter 4, from book java headfirst. I am confused by the output that I have. Why in the book, in solution section to this exercise right output for (x < 9) and (index < 5) = 14 1. Why I have output 81?

Please advise what wrong am I doing or explain what wrong with that.

```
public class Mix4 {
    int counter = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count = 0;
        Mix4[] m4a = new Mix4[20];
        int x = 0;
        while (x < 9){
            m4a[x] = new Mix4();
            m4a[x].counter = m4a[x].counter + 1;
            count = count + 1;
            count = count = m4a[x].maybeNew(x);
            x = x + 1;
        }
        System.out.println(count + " "  + m4a[1].counter);
    }

    public int maybeNew(int  index){
        if (index < 5){
            Mix4 m4 =  new Mix4();
            m4.counter =  m4.counter + 1;
            return counter;
        }
         return index;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `count = count = m4a[x].maybeNew(x);` really what's written in the book? That looks very suspicious

Comment: You cannot assume that everyone has a copy of that book!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake is on line 15 and line 27:

The line:

```
count = count = m4a[x].maybeNew(x);
```

should be replaced by

```
count = count + m4a[x].maybeNew(x);
```

The line:

```
return index;
```

should be replaced by:

```
return 0;
```

This will give you the output as 14 1

This is as per the book example mentioned by you (Java Head First, page 90)

Comment: Hint: Instead of line numbers it's easier to read which (incorrect) line should be replaced with which one

Comment: I really appreciated the help! It's really easy stuff, but after when you learn a lot, even that could be difficult! Thank you!